# Change the look on site contents or site collection level

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme, modern-experience, modern-pages, spcolor

I just applied a custom company theme on SharePoint modern site (which works perfectly fine) using tutorial from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview. I can find the "Change the Look" button after the "Site Permissions" button as per screenshot below:

[image]
[image]

However I found that "Change the Look" button is not available on other sites which **web template type is "Publishing Site"**. I just need to change the colors within the modern "Site Contents".

[image]

I tried to manually access the design gallery from `/_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx` and it still doesn't show any of my new color palettes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Office 365 update just added the "Change the look" on Publishing Site - Site Contents.

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t see Change the look on the Settings menu, you probably don’t have permission to manage this option. For more information, see Understanding permission levels in SharePoint or ask your administrator.

Article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-look-of-your-SharePoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the answer I'm seeking for as I am the administrator and developer. You would notice that "Change the look" option is not available when you're on classic publishing site contents(`/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx`) compared to what in modern site.